# issue in removing index.php in codeigniter 3 while using redirect method

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

in codeigniter 3.1.3, while i'm using **redirect('Admin','refresh')** method from **Login** controller, in url it shows **localhost/rsufadmin/index.php/Admin**.... i have a htaccess file which contains

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

if i manually type **localhost/rsufadmin/Admin** , Admin controller work just fine... but i have to go to other controllers from a controller. So, how can i remove this index.php part from url??
i have some screenshot below to make it understand easier... [while using redirect method from controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKbf2.png),.. [while manually entering url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3Euz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|asset|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: same result... :(

Comment: remove index.php in config.php

Comment: $config['index_page'] = 'index.php'; change  $config['index_page'] = '';